# Does Resist Energy stack with racial traits granting energy resistances?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, racial-traits, stacking, resistance, aasimar

The Aasimar race has a trait that grants the following:

> [Celestial Resistance](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/races/other-races/featured-races/arg-aasimar/#Standard_Racial_Traits): Aasimars have acid resistance 5, cold resistance 5, and electricity resistance 5.

If I cast [Resist Energy](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/r/resist-energy) on an Aasimar choosing cold, does it replace the racial resist or stack with it for the spell duration?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Spell and racial energy resistances don't stack.

As specified [in the rules about Energy Resistance](https://www.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?Name=Energy%20Resistance&Category=Special%20Abilities) :

> A creature with resistance to energy has the ability (usually extraordinary) to ignore some damage of a certain type per attack, but it does not have total immunity.
>   [...]
>   This resistance does not stack with the resistance that a spell might provide.

Therefore, in your example, the racial resistance will be replaced by Resist Energy for the spell duration.